# Creating php datetime object with 12-8-2011 and 13:14 variables

Tags: php, datetime

I have a form that has a datePicker and two dropdown boxes for the time.  How would I go about converting variables similar to 12-08-2011 and 13:14 into a valid php datetime object?

Comment: 12-08 = 12th of August or 8th of December?

Comment: Sorry, it would be the 8th of December in the example above.  The final DateTime object will be stored as a MySQL DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-j-Y H:i', "{$date} {$time}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '12-08-2011';
$b = '13:14';
$date = new DateTime($a.' '.$b);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

2011-08-12 13:14:00
```